# can MQTT be used to implement Request / Response behavior

Tags: android, http, mqtt

We are planning to use MQTT to deliver messages from our server to an android devices 
we decided to go with the open source server mosquitto.

in most of the cases this is enough.(Publishing / subscribing )
but we have a cases where the client need to send parameters and get response from the server.
i know the direct approach is to go with Http (Servlets for example) .
but can we achieve this using MQTT since it would  mean lower bandwidth consumption to the user ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it just requires careful design of your topic structure. As a very simple example, you could publish to `control/<client id>/request` and subscribe to `control/<client id>/response`

Comment: But assume that i have 10000 clients all requesting from the server if i implemented this using Http servlet for example i wouldnt have to worry about anything . but can the component(on the server side) handle all the requests coming at the same time ?. in another word what is the maximum number of topics the Client can subscribe for because for each client connecting we would have to add new subscription ??

Comment: Yes, that is a concern of course. Quotes like "My test involved 100K clients subscribed to 100K topics" (from https://lists.launchpad.net/mosquitto-users/msg00110.html ) should hopefully give you an idea of what is possible!

Comment: http://www.bitreactive.com/mqtt-request-response/ has this exact approach, its all about topic structure

Comment: @Clocker the link is dead

Answer (score 7):

As of MQTT version 5 this is possible. The specification has a Request/Response pattern specified.

Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916330/1137669

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you look at how [RabbitMQ handles RPC](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html). Although AMQP is different than MQTT there is quite a bit of high level carry over.

It boils down to you either need the ability to create ephemeral "Reply To" queues with correlation ids using message headers.  Or as @ralight said have two queues open for each client. The problem with two queues open for each client is of course ordering and thus you will have to use correlation ids and buffer and route internally (or drop till correlation id is found if your app is synchronous).

Answer (score 1):

You can also accomplish the same thing with xargs.

Here is a shell script as example:

```
mqtt_eg_link.sh

d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
mosquitto_pub -h <your host> -p 1880 -t status/ghost/log -m "$d >> eg listener running"
mosquitto_sub -h <your host> -p 1880 -t ghost | xargs -t -I {} cmd.exe /c eg.bat {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use wait/notify to transfer the publish/subscribe to request/response which are used in Dubbo framework DefaultFuture,