# Request response pattern with mosca MQTT

Tags: node.js, mqtt, message-queue, publish-subscribe, mosca

Is there any way to implement request-response pattern with mosca MQTT to "check reply from the client and re publish if i dont receive expected reply within expected time".

I believe this is possible in Mqtt 5, but as of now, I have to use Mosca broker with QoS 1(which support until Mqtt 3.1.1)

I am looking for a Node js workaround to achieve this.

Comment: You can implement a request-response pattern with any MQTT broker but, prior to v5, you need to implement this yourself (either have a single reply-to topic and a message ID, or include a specific reply-to topic within each message). Even with MQTT v5 you would need to implement the idle timeout bit yourself. Note that if you are using QOS 1/2 then the broker will take care of resending the message (until it receives a PUBACK/PUBCOMP) so resending the message may be counterproductive (lots of identical messages queued up while the comms link is down).

Comment: @Brits Thank you . Do you have any reference to follow to implement request -response pattern with MQTT ( not MQTT v5)

Answer (score 4):

As per my comment you can implement a request-response pattern with any MQTT broker but, prior to v5, you need to implement this yourself (either have a single reply-to topic and a message ID, or include a specific reply-to topic within each message).

Because MQTT 3.11 itself does not provide this functionality directly and there is no standard format for the MQTT payload (just some bytes!) its not possible to come up with a generic implementation (a unique id of some kind is needed within the request). This is resolved in MQTT v5 through the ability to include [properties](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Properties) including [Response Topic](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901114) and [Correlation Data](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901115). For earlier versions you are stuck with adding some extra information into the payload (using whatever encoding mechanism you choose).

There are a few Stack Overflow questions that might provide some insight:

- [MQTT topic names for request/response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392645/mqtt-topic-names-for-request-response)
- [RPC style request with MQTT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483012/rpc-style-request-with-mqtt)

Other articles:

- [Eclipse Kura](https://eclipse.github.io/kura/ref/mqtt-namespace.html#mqtt-requestresponse-conversations)
- [Stock Explorer](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1159256/Stock-Explorer-Using-Pub-Sub-for-Request-Response)
- [IoT Application Development Using Request-Response Pattern with MQTT](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=k2ZNDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=Request-Response%20Kari%20Syst%C3%A4&source=bl&ots=IlXvGGQkoY&sig=ACfU3U02juuOuL4adSnuxL_MB5ymwAGbkA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ8dKq1aDnAhXETX0KHWE9A28Q6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=Request-Response%20Kari%20Syst%C3%A4&f=false) (Academic article - purchase needed to read whole thing).
- [Amazon device shadow MQTT topics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/device-shadow-mqtt.html) (e.g. send message to `$aws/things/thingName/shadow/get` and AWS IoT responds on `/get/accepted` or `/get/rejected`).

Here are a few node packages (note: these have not been updated for some time and I have not reviewed the code):

- [replyer](https://github.com/jsdario/replyer)
- [resmetry](https://github.com/mohdrashid/resmetry)

Even with MQTT v5 you would need to implement the idle timeout bit yourself. If you are using QOS 1/2 then the broker will take care of resending the message (until it receives a PUBACK/PUBCOMP) so resending the message may be counterproductive (lots of identical messages queued up while the comms link is down)

Comment: Thank you for your awesome references. I started to implement the request-response pattern on the broker side. I have added the  approach as an answer to the same question

Answer (score 0):

The summary of the workflow i have done

- Adding "Correlation Id" for each message
- The expected reply is stored in Redis as the Request Payload(Request with the 
  Correlation Id as a key) to compare response from the client.
- The entry will be removed from Redis if the expected message is
  equivalent to the expected response topic and payload.
- Time out uses node cron jobs for each response from the client to
  Server.