# MQTT delivery acknowledgement

Tags: mqtt

Let's say I know that i have one subscriber per topic. Is there any way I can publish to an mqtt broker and block until I get acknowledgement from the subscriber? (or even if i had multiple subscribers, is there a way to block until at least 1 subscriber acks?)

Comment: You can implement request-response pattern as per my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59888811/request-response-pattern-with-mosca-mqtt/59916330#59916330) - in your case the response would just be an acknowledgement.

Comment: oh thanks! do you know if this is easily possible with aws iot core?

Comment: It really depends on what is processing the messages (probably best to ask this as another question with full details of how the messages are being processed).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is NO end to end delivery notification in the MQTT protocol.

If you want to have delivery notification you have to implement it yourself.